# Why I get exception when use mysql-connector-java in Spring Boot project?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have Spring Boot 2.0 project and I'm using Spring Data JPA.
For now I should write test for my repository. Here is my repository

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer>{}
```

My main class also very simple it just has annotation and main class.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class PhoneBookApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PhoneBookApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

All problem is with test.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class ProxyUserRepositoryTest {

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;


@Test 
public void createUser(){
    User u = new User();
    u.setFullName("FullName");
    u.setPassword("123456");
    u.setUserName("Name");
    userRepository.save(u);
}
}
```

When I run that I get error

```
    Description:

Parameter 0 of method testEntityManager in org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManagerAutoConfiguration required a bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' in your configuration.

2018-03-23 17:12:12.360 ERROR 628 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@96def03] to prepare test instance [com.phonebook.repository.datajpa.ProxyUserRepositoryTest@61230f6a]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125) ~[spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:107) ~[spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117) ~[spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83) ~[spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:44) ~[spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:242) ~[spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227) [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291) [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246) [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97) [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190) [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:369) [surefire-junit4-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:275) [surefire-junit4-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:239) [surefire-junit4-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:160) [surefire-junit4-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:373) [surefire-booter-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:334) [surefire-booter-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:119) [surefire-booter-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:407) [surefire-booter-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'testEntityManager' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/TestEntityManagerAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'testEntityManager' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:729) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:470) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1250) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:138) ~[spring-boot-test-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) ~[spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117) ~[spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1509) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:815) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:721) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 46 common frames omitted
```

And this happens only when I use mysql-connector-java which I must use. 
I've tried use h2 and with that works fine.
Also can provide my application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springboot
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

Comment: Did you add MySQL Connector/J to the dependencies of your project?

Comment: Yes I've added mysql-connector-java. And when I change this dependency to h2, test starts work.

Comment: @user7431083 key point in the log is `Caused by: org...UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'testEntityManager' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/TestEntityManagerAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'testEntityManager' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}`

Comment: And `No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}`

Comment: By default, tests annotated with @DataJpaTest will use an embedded in-memory database. It's why I get exception :/

Comment: But can I somehow use mysql for testing? I've found way by using @AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace=Replace.NONE) but I get same error as I have.